# JWT builder adds an unwanted new line

Tags: java, jwt

I have developped a Java EE webapp that generates a JWT using custom arguments.
It mainly works well, but in some rare cases, the generated string (my JWT) contains a break line, and this is not supposed to happen (cause this JWT is supposed to be part of an URL).

More information : 
On my computer, this bug NEVER appears (like .. NEVER), but on others it sometimes appears (with same data, same workspace ... same everything).
The only thing that change is the OS (Win 7 & Win 10, both x64)

Dev environment:

- JAVA 1.7.45
- Apache Tomcat 7.0.82
- JWT API : 0.9.0

My code :

```
        String id = "someId";
        int tokenDuration = jwtDuration* 60 * 1000; 
        SignatureAlgorithm signatureAlgorithm = SignatureAlgorithm.HS256;

        long nowMillis = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
        Date now = new Date(nowMillis);

        // Hash key
        byte[] apiKeySecretBytes = TextCodec.BASE64.decode(jwtKey);

        long expMillis = nowMillis + tokenDuration;
        Date exp = new Date(expMillis);

        // JWT building
        JwtBuilder builder = Jwts.builder()
                .setId(id)
                .setIssuedAt(now)
                .setExpiration(exp)
                .setIssuer(applicationName)
                .claim("user", myUser)
                .signWith(signatureAlgorithm, apiKeySecretBytes);

        return builder.compact();
```

Could someone explain this magic to me ? :D
Thanks a lot

Comment: Where exactly is the break inserted? Can you please include a sample JWT that has this error?

Comment: Here is an example, but it's never the same : 
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJqdGkiOiJhcG9jb25uZWN0UFJJTU8iLCJpYXQiOjE1MjI4NDgxMDYsImV4cCI6MTUyMzQ0ODA0
NiwiaXNzIjoiQVBPLUNvbm5lY3QiLCJ1c2VyIjoiQUQxMzExMDQifQ.R8C_HuXje9oLP714o1eKOIB5kRcG9mkS85Kg6jvD_QQ

Comment: And where is the line break? After `0ODA0`? Note that this JWT is valid.

Comment: In this case, after DA0 yes. and you're right, it's valid, but the problem is that this JWT is purposed to be a URL parameter like : http://myserv.com?jwt=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJqdGkiOiJh...... And a line break and an URL aren't good friends :D
It seems to be a problem with some version of Tomcat (7.0.82 here). In a 7.0.85, this problem never shows up.

Comment: Am I alone in this case? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update : the new version 0.10.5 of jjwt-api (jjwt-impl etc...) fix this problem ! So everything's fine now :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not a Java developer, but if this token is valid JWT, you can just remove newlines from it:

```
...
return builder.compact().replaceAll("\n","")
```

But I cant explain why such things happens!

Comment: Hi ignoras, ty for your answer. Actually, you can't do it because it "changes" the JWT (the newline is en entire part of the JWT). But it seems that the new version 0.10.5 of jjwt-api (jjwt-impl etc...) fix this problem ! So everything's fine now :)